# ubuntu nginx vertual host issue not redirecting to desire folder

Tags: php, redirect, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I have added 2 domains to ubuntu droplets. **a.com** and **b.com**. Both A Record redirecting to IP.

I also creating virtual host for both domains. like

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html/b.com;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name b.com www.b.com;

        location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

But b.com is not redirecting to desire folder. When i access domain from url. Its redirect to main IP folder like **/var/www/html** instead of **/var/www/html/b.com**

**My default virtual host**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html/;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

i follow these instruction but still not working : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

```
server_name _;
```

is a catch-all server and if it comes first in your configuration it will be served first. You can read more about this here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

If you change it to

```
server_name a.com www.a.com;
```

it should work for you.
I recommend you to read this part of the documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Full configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name b.com www.b.com;

    root /var/www/html/b.com/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
             try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;

            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it works. but b.com and www.b.com is not working

Comment: it's also redirect to a.com

Comment: did you restart your nginx-service?

Comment: yes i restart server every thing fine like sudo nginx -t and sudo systemctl restart nginx.

Comment: what nginx version do you use?

Comment: i  am using 16.04

Comment: I meant the version of nginx. try nginx -v. I have added a working configuration which is on my own servers.

Comment: Please adjust paths like /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

Comment: i am using nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

Comment: try the configuration I have added.

Comment: Remove your configuration for the main html-folder and check if the b.com-configuration is matching at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142048/discussion-between-m-arfan-and-oliver).